# Interpreting the output of elasticsearch GET query

Tags: elasticsearch

The output of the `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v"` is as follows:

| index | shard | prirep | state | docs | store | ip | node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_index | 1 | p | STARTED | 0 | 283b | 127.0.0.1 | Deepaks-MacBook-Pro-2.local |
| test_index | 1 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 1 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 0 | p | STARTED | 1 | 12.5kb | 127.0.0.1 | Deepaks-MacBook-Pro-2.local |
| test_index | 0 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 0 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |

And the output of the query `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test_index/_search?size=1000" | json_pp` is as follows:

```
{
   "_shards" : {
      "failed" : 0,
      "skipped" : 0,
      "successful" : 2,
      "total" : 2
   },
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_id" : "101",
            "_index" : "test_index",
            "_score" : 1,
            "_source" : {
               "in_stock" : -4,
               "name" : "pizza maker",
               "prize" : 10
            },
            "_type" : "_doc"
         }
      ],
      "max_score" : 1,
      "total" : {
         "relation" : "eq",
         "value" : 1
      }
   },
   "timed_out" : false,
   "took" : 2
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** As you can see, only text_index 0 primary shard has the data (from the output of first query), why `successful` key inside the `_shards` key has the value of 2?

Also, there is only 1 document, then why the value of `total` key inside `_shards` key is 2?

Answer (score 0):

`test_index` has two primary shards and four unassigned replica shards (probably because you have a single node). Since a primary shard is a partition of your index, a document can only be stored in a single primary shard, in your case primary shard 0.

`total: 2` means that the search was run over the two primary shards of your index (i.e. 100% of the data) and `successful: 2` means that all primary shards responded. So you know you can trust the response to have searched over all your `test_index` data.

There's nothing wrong here.